# Not able to pass command output to a variable and use later in another task in ansible

Tags: ansible

## My Ansible playbook.

- hosts: all

```
vars:

      alias_name: '{{ alias }}'
      upload_file: '{{ upload }}'
      pack1: /home/ansible

 tasks:
  - name: Copy file with owner and permissions
    copy:
     src: '{{ upload_file }}'
     dest: '{{ pack1 }}'
     owner: ansible
     group: ansible
     mode: '0777'

 - name: return motd to registered var
    shell: "ls -Art | tail -n 1"
    args:
     chdir: '{{ pack1 }}'
     register: mymotd


  - name: Import SSL certificate from google.com to a given cacerts keystore
    java_cert:
     cert_path: '{{ pack1 }}/{{ mymotd.stdout }}'
     cert_alias: '{{ alias_name }}'
     keystore_path: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-7.b13.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts'
     keystore_pass: changeit
     state: present
```

ERROR:

```
FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "ls -Art | tail -n 1", 
            "chdir": "/home/ansible", 
            "register": "mymotd", 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: register Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, stdin_add_newline, strip_empty_ends, warn"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************
172.16.217.129             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Is there any other way you can recommend me to do the same? My main aim is to pass command output to a variable and use that variable later to append in cert path.

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the indentation of `return motd to registered var` task like below. Also use `shell` module instead of `command` to be able to use operations like "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&".

Please format ansible playbook as per correct [YAML syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax).

```
  - name: return motd to registered var
    shell: "ls -Art | tail -n 1"
    args:
      chdir: '{{ pack1 }}'
    register: mymotd
```

Comment: I know OP originally made the mistake, but you'll need to switch `command:` to `shell:` in order for that `| tail` to do anything

Comment: Right, totally overlooked the actual command since the formatting itself was incorrect.

Comment: Hi now have changed command to shell , and also correct the identation but its still showing the same error ....

Comment: ```fatal: [172.16.217.129]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "ls -Art | tail -n 1", 
            "_uses_shell": true, 
            "chdir": "/home/ansible", 
            "register": "mymotd", 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: register Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, stdin_add_newline, strip_empty_ends, warn"
} ```

Comment: Indentation is still not correct as far as I can see from your update, specially around vars, name and register. Have a closer look at the code I have added.